# parse html from a web page which uses infinite scroll

Tags: java, jsoup

I would like to parse html from web page which use infinite scroll, such as: pinterest.com so as to get all items.

```
public List<String> popularTagsPinterest(String tag) throws Exception {

    List<String> results = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect(
                urlPinterest + tag + "&eq=%23" + tag + "&etslf=6622&term_meta[]=%23" + tag + "%7Cautocomplete%7C0")
                .timeout(90000).get();
        Elements img1 = doc.select("a.pinImageWrapper img.pinImg");
        for (Element e : img1) {
            results.add(e.attr("src"));
            System.out.println(e.attr("src"));
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
    return results;
}
```

Comment: You can't get all elements from a webpage which uses javascript to load content with Jsoup. You need to execute the javascript code and emulate a browser scroll to make it load all elements, which is something that a parser can't do.

Comment: There is an API that launches your local browser and emulates scroll (infinitely if you like). I just don't remember the name...

Comment: I believe that jsoup has an execute script method

Comment: @BackSlash , please I need more informations .
NB : I'm using angular in front end

Comment: Look into headless browser with js support: HtmlUnit, phantomjs, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Get base url and the ajax call for loading another part can do.

Check this page, is a good example.

https://blog.scrapinghub.com/2016/06/22/scrapy-tips-from-the-pros-june-2016